# Is it possible to run ui automation from an android activity?

Tags: android, automation, monkeyrunner

I do a lot search, lots of posts are talking about sending UI events (such as touch, keys) from host workstation (PC) to connected device.

My problem is, i need kick off the automation test from device, i don't have source access of the apk to be tested. I looked robotium, which modifies the apk's signing signature in order to do instrumentation test, but my customer forbidden me to modify the package.

My question is, is it possible to use monkey runner (or monkey) in an android activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is outside the permissions of an app. If your device was rooted you could theoretically do this though.